# Filter an NSArray which contains custom objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have `UISearchBar`, `UITableView`, a web service which returns a `NSMutableArray` that contain objects like this:

```
//Food.h
Food : NSObject { 
    NSString *foodName;
    int idFood;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *foodName;
```

And the array:

```
Food *food1 = [Food alloc]initWithName:@"samsar" andId:@"1"];
Food *food2 = [Food alloc] initWithName:@"rusaramar" andId:@"2"];

NSSarray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:food1, food2, nil];
```

How do I filter my array with objects with name beginning with "sa"?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can filter any array like you'd like to with the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;

[array filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject.foodName hasPrefix:searchBar.text];
}];
```

This will filter the array "in-place" and is only accessible on an `NSMutableArray`. If you'd like to get a new array that's been filtered for you, use the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` `NSArray` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what's [evalutedObject objectName] ??

Comment: `objectName` was the property on the `NSObject` subclass in your question. If you want to filter based on a different property of the objects in your array, just use than property name instead.

Comment: I am sorry, i am doing like this : myObject *obj = [myObject new];
    myArray =   [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [[obj objectName] hasPrefix:searchTextField.text];
    }]];

Comment: and it's not working, myArray is the array witch contani my objects

Comment: What does the definition of `myObject` look like? In your question, it seems to have an `NSString` property (or instance variable) called `objectName`. Can you please expand your question with more of `myOjbect.h`?

Comment: OK so what you need to do is add a property called `foodName` in the header file and `@synthesize foodName` in the implementation file. I'll update my answer.

Comment: A block predicate seems like overkill for this case. You could just use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foodName beginswith %@", searchBar.text]`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the `evaluatedObject` is food1, then food2, etc. It's all of the objects in the array, one-by-one.

Comment: Tanks, it's working with : [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foodName beginswith[cd] %@", searchBar.text]

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *predString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(foodName BEGINSWITH[cd] '%@')", @"sa"];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predString];

NSArray *array = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```