# NSPredicate for custom objects not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, nspredicate

I have array of custom objects, `_momsArray`. shown here is single object of such array:

```
Custom *yourMom {
  name = @"Sally M. Brown";
  age = 54;
  weight = 43.2;
}
```

I run my predicate inside searchBar delegate:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if ([searchText length]<=0) {
        _tableDataArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:_momsArray];
    } else{

        // filtered _tableDataArr
        NSString *filter = @"name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@";
        NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:filter, searchText];
        NSArray *filteredArr  = [_momsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        _tableDataArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:filteredArr];
    }
    [_momTable reloadData];
}
```

This doesn't give expected result. For example, when I type S, sally doesn't appear at all. What is wrong with my code?

**EDIT**: The string in the custom objects contains punctuations and therefore it is not the same as other answers.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint to see what goes into filteredArr?

Comment: Yes. THat is how I know there is nothing returned.

Comment: Could the punctuations in "name" field causing nspredicate unable to work properly?

Comment: @NiravD no I want to search name by first letter. So if I type S, then Sally, Simon, etc should come up.

Comment: I think you may need to put your variable inside single quotes, like:

`NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"name BEGINSWITH[cd] '%@' ", searchText]];`

Comment: @Rikh that doesnt work either.

Comment: you should check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558335/filter-an-nsarray-which-contains-custom-objects

Comment: Your code is working fine...i checked it.

Comment: Yea the code is working. The changes is not reflected due to my mistake - i load a different array elsewhere onto the cells LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter an array with custom objects you can use this code.

```
NSString *str = @"text";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.name contains[c] %@", str];
NSArray *arrFiltered = [self.arrDataObject filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is not properly generated so use below code :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", text];
arrFilterData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[arrDataList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

**OUTPUT**

Before search

[image]

After search

[image]

**And with code**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", text];
arrFilterData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[arrDataList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

> Edit

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: This make my app crash.

Comment: what is the crash reason?

Comment: That is not my question is it? Yours is just simple array of strings. mine are array of custom objects. Try put some dots in your string array see if that still works.

Comment: It is a custom array where I am picking just name like `Sally`

Comment: Put some dots in your Peacock string, like Pea.cock. Then try it.

Comment: your code is fine and correct, but it is used for arrays search not array of dictionary search, better modify your answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik My answer is in multiple format, but my code work is not working is his system. As he is saying my code crashes his project. I still don't know how.! :(

Comment: OMG. Your initial answer DID cause my app to crash! The edited answer are simply the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
NSMutableArray *filteredArr = [[_momsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred]mutableCopy];
```